# Entity framework 6 future is generating duplicate queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

Following code is written in entity framework 6 and [entity framework plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-query-future) library (futures)

```
using (var ctx = _contextCreator.PortalContext())
{
    var q = "";
    ctx.Database.Log = s => q+=s;
    
    var a = ctx.ArticleIcons.Take(1).Future();
    var b = ctx.ArticleIcons.Take(3).Future();
    
    var aResult = a.ToList();
}
```

This is output of "q" variable, which is otputing generated SQL queries. Is it possible to avoid execution of 4 queries, because there are only 2 queries in the code?

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [c].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [c].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [c].[CssClass] AS [CssClass]
    FROM [dbo].[ArticleIcons] AS [c]
-- Executing at 25.3.2022. 9:41:47 +01:00
-- Completed in 29 ms with result: null

SELECT TOP (3) 
    [c].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [c].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [c].[CssClass] AS [CssClass]
    FROM [dbo].[ArticleIcons] AS [c]
-- Executing at 25.3.2022. 9:41:47 +01:00
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: null

Opened connection at 25.3.2022. 9:41:48 +01:00
-- EF+ Query Future: 1 of 2
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [c].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [c].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [c].[CssClass] AS [CssClass]
    FROM [dbo].[ArticleIcons] AS [c]
;

-- EF+ Query Future: 2 of 2
SELECT TOP (3) 
    [c].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [c].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [c].[CssClass] AS [CssClass]
    FROM [dbo].[ArticleIcons] AS [c]
;

-- Executing at 25.3.2022. 9:41:48 +01:00
-- Completed in 53 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Closed connection at 25.3.2022. 9:41:48 +01:00
```

Comment: Yeah, don't use futures ;) Do you actually need futures for something as simple as this? You might find that futures is implemented at a lower level than where the logging is, so the logging it not aware that the first 2 queries migh not actually be going through to the server

Comment: @ChrisSchaller this is just a mock query for the sake of question. Original query is a lot bigger and more complex, and consists of 13 queries, but the issue remains the same.

Comment: I'm saying your logs do not indicate actual db connectivity, I haven't used this lib in a few years so can't easily check, but profile it in the db to confirm the queries are being deferred.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller thanks. It makes sense. If you like, you can type it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is logged 2 times for the following reasons:

The first time, the library generates both queries (do not execute them, just generate them). However, to generate it correctly it must call the [interceptor](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/src/shared/Z.EF.Plus._Core.Shared/EF6/ObjectQuery/GetCommandTextAndParameters.cs#L50) ReaderExecuting and ReaderExecuting which log both queries. This step is mandatory has some provider such as `MySql`/custom user code change the query and parameter.

The second time, after the queries have been combined, the library calls the the [DbInterception.Dispatch.Command.Reader](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/src/shared/Z.EF.Plus.QueryFuture.Shared/QueryFutureBatch.cs#L192) interceptor which log the combined query.

So while the query has been logged 2 times due to limitation, only the combined query has been executed in the database server.

Comment: Thanks Jon! That's how I thought it was working, I'm glad you have provided us a definitive answer on this.